# What is complete authentic story of demon Tripurasura?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, other-religions, shiva-purana

According to this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripurasura) page of Tripurasura, Tripurasura was killed by Lord Shiva because he followed a ***Adharmic Religion*** which was created by Lord Vishnu to lure him to the path of Adharma. After Lord Shiva killing demon Tripurasura, those shaven head religious teachers asked Lord Vishnu what to do and Lord Vishnu ordered them to go to desert where there were no humans and come back during Kaliyuga.

- What's the complete authentic story of Killing of Tripurasura, according to Shiva Purana?
- What could be that Religion? Is it Islam or Christianity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story of creating new Dharma, which is against Vedic Dharma, to destroy virtuousness of asuras, was mentioned in [Chapter 4 to 10 of Rudrasamhita - Yuddhakanda section of Shiva Purana](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/21319/7/Part2_Chapter5_795-874p.pdf) ( Pg:820-846).

> For causing obstacles in their virtuous activities, Vishnu of great
>   brilliance, created a PURUSHA born of himself. He had a shaven
>   head, wore dirty clothes, held a woven wicker vessel in his hand and a
>   roll of cotton in his hand when he shook at every step. His hands
>   tucking at the cloth were weak. His face was pale and weak. In a
>   faltering voice he was muttering "Dharma,Dharma".
>
> (Footnote says, According to present context Vishnu created a delusive
>   teacher called Maayamoha who created as Maaya Saastra of 16,00,000
>   verses in Apabhramsa,preaching Jina Dharma for Misguiding the Asuras.
>   They preached Non violence, forbade Shruti and Smaarta rituals,
>   discarded Varnasrama System,created an order for women which resulted
>   in leaving home and leading the life of nuns. In some versions the
>   role is assigned to Brihaspati,Preceptor of Gods who in guise of their
>   preceptor Sukra deludes the Asuras. For details,see
>   Maayamohanaprakarana in Padma,Vishnu ,Linga and Matsya.)
>
> Vishnu said,
>
> "O intelligent one , born of me,you are certainly identical with me in
>   form.Know why you have been created. I shall tell you. You are born of
>   me. You can perform my task. You are my own. Certainly you will be worthy
>   of worship. Let your name be Arihat. You will have other auspicious
>   names too. I shall assign to you a place afterwards. O you who wield
>   Maayaa,create a deceptive sacred text of 16,00,000 verses contrary to
>   Srutis and Smritis, wherein Varnas and Aasramas shall be eschewed .Let
>   the holy text be in Aprabrahmsa Language. Let there be emphasis on
>   actions. O you with shaven head, you shall go to city of Tripuras,
>   reveal the Tasmik acts and destroy the three cities. After that,O
>   great one you shall go the desert stay there carrying your own duties
>   and activities till advent of Kali Yuga. At my bidding your cult shall
>   certainly expand."
>
> Saying this Vishnu vanished.
>
> Then the ascetic of shaven head acting in accordance with Vishnu's
>   behest created four disciples of like form as himself and taught them
>   the deceptive cult.

Those Shaven heads then went to City of Tripuras and taught this deceptive cult. When Asuras stopped worshipping Shiva, Shiva killed them.

> After kneeling down before Gods,tonsured heads ask Gods" where shall
>   we go?"
>
> Vishnu and other gods said,
>
> "From now onwards in the Kali age those follow this cult will be faced
>   with disastrous results. We tell you the truth. There is no doubt about
>   it. O brave tonsured heads, you shall stay incognito in the desert
>   region. That is my behest. When Kali age begins,you can propagate your
>   cult. In kali age,deluded fools will follow your cult."
>
> (Footnote says the desert is identified as desert Maru lying to the
>   north-west of Gujarat or and to the north of Dwaraka which is also called as
>   Thar or Rajaputana desert.)

That religion could be Jina dharma (Jainism).

Answer (score 0):

It is Buddhism. Trailokavijaya is Tripurasura, among the three Heruka deities. This is why Buddhism is Anti-Shaivism and Anti-Vedanta. These facts are obvious in Tibetan Buddhism. They refer to Shiva as Maheshvara.

The second Tripurasura started Islam, and the third started Judaism a little prior. Christ Jesus could be considered the whistleblower on these latter two. Buddhism, though, still fools Hindus even today. These are the triumvirate of openly anti-Hindu religions. Christianity, owing to it's unfinished message as per the untimely demise of Jesus, has many misguided Christians seeing Hindus as the enemy, or as anti-Christian, which is to my understanding not the case in real life.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).