# Are other religions just an illusion to end kaliyuga?

Tags: other-religions, kali-yuga, kalki

I respect all human beings, but I did not get their religion, it is more like illusion to me. illusion is something like human can't escape from it, Here is my opinion about how world can end, or how kaliyuga can be end.

1. Man vs Man : In this war people don't fight in the name of religion they just want land and wealth. If they get it what they desire, then any world war will be over, but kaliyuga will not end.
2. God vs Man: We all know god can not even punish evil or demon if they don't do anything wrong, we all know the [story of tripusura](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8755/10405). So the kaliyuga will be never end, if only good people live here(Without violence), but due to cyclic period of every yuga it should be end, so GOD can do some kind of illusion to make it happen. I know people can get escape from all of this, because [kaliyuga is not hard as other three yuga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2147/10405).
3. Religion vs Religion: As I said to make the end of kaliyuga, god can make illusion of adharma, which will fight with dharma and adharma will conquer the world and then [lord kalki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki)(the avatar of lord vishnu) will kill all adharma people and make the end of kaliyuga and start satyuga again.

I know in kali puran it is referenced that people in the end of kaliyuga don't pray to god, they will do more sins and hence kalki will destroy all of them, but for me it is partial true, because if people do more sins then they may take birth in other jivas(like animals), and kaliyuga will never end. So What make sense better is, their(Mleccha) illusion dharma(Adharma) will conquer the whole world and then god kalki will kill all of them, so the cycle of kaliyug will end and satyuga can start again. [Read this Wikipedia article line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki)(The Padma Purana describes that Kalki will end the age of kali and kill all mlecchas).

So do you think this is how the kaliyuga will be end? Do you think other mlecchas religion(Which establish after kaliyuga) are just illusion? like in trupusura case? I know my question is bit off topic, but my intention is not hurt any human belief (since even if it is illusion then it is created by parbramhan to end kaliyuga, so I respect them). I welcome your atman thoughts in comments box as well, if my question is vote to close.

Update:

1. My meaning of melleche is only about adharma which is establish outside of arya country, since adharma can't establish with santan dharma.
2. [The demon kali family tree is interesting to note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_(demon)#Family_lineage), it indicated that people can born with this characteristics as well.

Comment: Even the Sanatana Dharmis will become sinful. So we can't blame everything on others.

Comment: Mlecchas in this case doesn't refer to foreigners. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20387/is-sanatana-dharma-anti-foreigners

Comment: It's not about blame some religion to end of the world, our all human action will also responsible for that.May be in the next life we may born in other religion as well. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Here my thought about mlecchas means adharma religion which is come after kaliyuga.

Comment: Well not exactly an illusion mainly because I believe everything is real i.e. Visishtadvaita philosophy and everything in existence has some purpose so even this avidya has its purpose, as a tool for kali. Now it's upto a person to decide what he wants to follow Dharma or Adharma. Point to be noted Dharma is defined as "that which is declared in the Vedas" and it is further elaborated by seers/rishis in Dharma shastras like Manu Dharma Shastra.

Comment: @Yogi you did not get my point, there religion holly books contain many verse which allowed to kill any human who does not follow their religion, you should definitely read their holly books, it's not long btw, and after kaliyuga, we can see they conquer many country just to spread their religion, and people still believe it is fine, because there holly books does not say it is wrong, that's the illusion, checkout my update link 1, the kaliyuga is just stared and kali son adharma and himsa might already born and we can clearly see it if we read history.

Comment: Read their holly books and understand what they pray daily, and you will definitely say, yes this is adharma in kaliyaga, and it's born already. Their other holly books are consider as corrupt, because it does not spread violence, while current holly book is real and final and no one can change it's latter, because it is protected by their god, then why not that same god protect their old book? You should read all religion books, then you can connect all the dots. Puran does not mean real deamon or god will appear in kaliyuga, puran just said the truth in different form.

Answer (score 7):

Well, i can answer this question partially.

The Manu Smriti clearly states that any doctrines, traditions or philosophical systems that are not based on the Vedas are false and worthless.

> Manu Smriti 12.95. All those traditions (smriti) and those despicable
>   systems of philosophy, **which are not based on the Veda, produce no
>   reward after death; for they are declared to be founded on Darkness.**
>
> Manu Smriti 12.96. **All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda),
>   which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false**, because
>   they are of modern date

So, from the perspective of Hinduism (or Manu Smriti to be precise), the other religions can be termed as false or illusion (in your words), assuming that they were not created based on the Vedas.

However, whether they were created to accelerate the process of destruction is something that i can not answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am just sharing what knowledge i gathered. and what i understand on this. not assumption.

I heard about a script called "Akilathiratu Ammanai" which was written in tamil by sage who had dharsan of lord vishnu at his age of 3. He mentioned about end of kaliyug in this script.

There is no point of religion for end of yuga. Just take a example of own religion and this religion people on today date. 
 - people chat other in the of God. you can many fake gurus came today. this is the sign of kaliyug.

Good question you have pointed, if people do sin, they will get into animal world. so how can kaliyug will end?.

this is little complicate to explain. but i give some points. just see what is happening today and compare with 500 or 1000 years back.

even though a soul get animal birth, they were lived as they in the earth. but now a days you can see so much cow slaughters are there. people are very rude to kill dogs. is it?

so think, there will be a cosmic imbalance.

and question shouldn't be how many good and bad peoples are here.

how much good and bad things are happening here. in earlier time also sin people there. but there sins are not like today.

in sexually also, people are very down. today even mother and sons are having sex as i heard. so this is sign of kaliyug.

these all things are mentioned in that script, 500 years back. so you could sense change in environment and change culture, change in people mind set.

but today is not end of kaliyug. it has to go more. just think the deviation from 500 years back to till today. then imagine how the socity will be bad after 500 years.

so this is the process for kaliyug. in that time, destruction will be happen. panja poothas destroy the world. like tnusami, earth quake. the land will completely surrounded by sea. so i think, nothing will do with religious. but in that script, there mentioned, when kaliyug end, there will be safforon flag fly in our nation. India centeral to spirtual.

India is the last country will destroy finnaly. then end will with kanyakumari.

Comment: People think the end of kaliyuga will occur because people will do more sins, but more sins does not mean the end, the sins are purely affect karma and karma affects the re-birth cycle, but it does not make the end of world, the kali puran said only characteristic of kaliyuga, I know even hindu will do more sins, but the question is are other religion just illustion to make the end of world, since we found adam in our scripture as well, and due to he eat forbidden fruit he got curse from god, but the jesus was born from vergin womb and hence he did not inherits any sin from adam family tree.

Comment: Then other religion come because now jesus make all people are sin free and they will not fight with dharma, but adharma have many bad signs, you can [check this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_(demon)#Family_lineage), right now just adharma and hinsa is born but I think after few century I believe, people will born with fear and hell characteristics as well, i.e. fear from god, if they don't believe on their religion and will not do whatever said on their holly books i.e. kill other people who don't believe on our religion otherwise you will get hell.

Comment: Their holly books clear said it, but right now it is not the time is coming, hence they want peace, it may take few century and after that they will fear from hell, because they are not killing others who're not believing on their religion. I suggest you should read their holly books and then you will get everything what I want to say. Right now people said we want peach but their major verse talk totally different against humanity, so you should read their books first, it's not long btw.