Manusmriti on the Vedas
A poster writes

Manu smriti states that only Vedic darshana is true and all other darshanas are false.

A Quora entry lists the six Vedic Darshanas as

Nyaya: Focuses on logic and epistemology. It emphasizes the means of acquiring knowledge and the nature of reality through reasoning and debate.


Vaisheshika: Deals with metaphysics and categorization of reality. It classifies objects in the universe and discusses their properties and interactions.


Sankhya: A dualistic philosophy that outlines the distinction between consciousness (Purusha) and matter (Prakriti). It provides a framework for understanding the nature of existence.


Yoga: Centers on the practice of meditation and ethical living as a means to achieve spiritual insight and liberation (moksha). It includes the eight limbs of yoga as outlined by Patanjali.


Mimamsa: Focuses on the rituals and ethical aspects of the Vedas. It emphasizes the importance of dharma (duty) and the performance of rituals for societal and cosmic order.


Vedanta: Concerned with the nature of reality and the self. It explores the concepts of Brahman (the ultimate reality) and Atman (the individual soul), emphasizing the idea of unity between the two

Where does Manusmriti say this?

See 12.95 and 12.96

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20931/4732

Manusmriti doesn't explicitly mention darshanas but it does say other religious scriptures are false.

या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः । सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः
प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः ॥ ९५ ॥
Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection; as they
have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—XII.(95)

